# what is the curvature in differential geometrical \mathbb{R}^3

Tags: differential-geometry

If $s$ is the natural parameter, then $x'(s)$ and $x'(s+\Delta s)$ are unit vectors. Therefore the angle $\Delta \varphi$ between them is equal to $$ \Delta\varphi=x''(s)\Delta s+ o(\Delta s).$$

Def: The curvature $K(s)$ of the curve at the point $x(s)$ as the rate of rotation of the tangent, is equal to $$K(s)=|x{''}(s)| .$$

---

My Question: Why is there  $ \Delta\varphi=x''(s)\Delta s+ o(\Delta s)$ ?

Comment: Note that $x''(s)$ is a vector while $\Delta \varphi$ is a scalar so the expression does not make sense. It should be $\pm ||x''(s)||$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x'(s)$ is unit length, we can write

$$ x'(s) = \left( \cos \theta(s), \sin \theta(s) \right). $$

The choice of $\theta(s)$ is not unique but it won't affect the result. 
If we set $h = \Delta s$, we have $(\Delta \varphi)(h) = \theta(s + h) - \theta(s)$. Now, we can write a first order Taylor approximation for $\Delta \varphi$ around $h = 0$ and get

$$ (\Delta \varphi)(h) = (\Delta \varphi)(0) + (\Delta \varphi)'(0) \cdot h + o(h) = \theta'(s) \cdot h + o(h).$$

Finally,

$$ ||x''(s)|| = || \left( -\sin \theta(s) \theta'(s), \cos \theta(s) \theta'(s) \right)|| = \left| \theta'(s) \right| $$

and so

$$ \Delta \varphi = \theta'(s) \Delta s + o(\Delta s), \,\,\, |\theta'(s)| = ||x''(s)||. $$

Comment: thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I don't know where fail in my proof.

The curve x= x(s) is increase function in $R^2$. we have $$ \tan \theta_1 = x'(s), \tan\theta_2=x'(s+\Delta s)$$
$\dfrac{\tan \Delta\varphi}{\Delta s}=\dfrac{\tan\Delta \varphi}{\Delta\varphi}\dfrac{\Delta\varphi}{\Delta s}\to "\dfrac{\Delta \varphi}{\Delta s}" (\Delta s\to 0) ------(1)$.

In other word,

$$\dfrac{\tan\Delta\varphi}{\Delta s}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\tan\theta_2-\tan\theta_1}{1+\tan\theta_2\tan\theta_1}}{\Delta s}=\dfrac{x'(s+\Delta s)-x'(s)}{\Delta s}\dfrac{1}{1+x'(s+\Delta s)x'(s)}\to x''(s)\dfrac{1}{2} (\Delta s\to 0)-----(2)$$ 
since $x'(s+\Delta s)x'(s)\to |x'(s)|^2=1 (\Delta s \to 0)$.

Finally,
$$ \dfrac{\Delta\varphi}{\Delta s}=\dfrac{x''(s)}{2}$$ !

Note: In (2), we can use Taylor to have result $o(\Delta s)$